# how to run a python code using cmd.exe from a C# application?

Tags: c#, python, winforms

I have an application where i am trying to run a python from a c# application. i have tried creating the python runtime environment and run the code, but as my python code is importing some modules from another python file it throws an exception (import exception). i have tried the following code:

```
var ipy = Python.CreateRuntime();
                dynamic test = ipy.UseFile(@"file path");
                test.Simple();
                Console.Read();
```

I hvae another idea of running it through cmd prompt, but i don't know how do it. i want open to cmd.exe and execute the python file and i want it such that the user enters the filename in c# aplication and on clicking the run button the code is executed through cmd.exe and the output is again shown in c# application.
Any other suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: Try a simple case.  Is it possible to run a Python script that does not import from another Python file? Also please post your exception as that will give us an idea of what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would do the job: the following example runs cmd which runs TCL script (that wat I have installed on my computer) you only need to replace the command to run Python and add your script file.
Pay attention to the " & exit" comming after your script file name - this makes the cmd exit after your script exits.

```
string fileName = "C:\\Tcl\\example\\hello.tcl";
        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/K tclsh " + fileName + " & exit")
        {
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };
        p.Start();

        string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        p.WaitForExit();

        Console.WriteLine(output);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

[Update]

After Python installation and testing, that would be the code to run python script with cmd:

```
 string fileName = @"C:\Python27\example\hello_world.py";

        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/K " + fileName + " & exit")
        {
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };
        p.Start();

        string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        p.WaitForExit();

        Console.WriteLine(output);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Also you can do the same without the CMD process:

```
string fileName = @"C:\Python27\example\hello_world.py";

        Process p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Python27\python.exe",  fileName )
        {
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };
        p.Start();

        string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        p.WaitForExit();

        Console.WriteLine(output);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: i tried your method by replacing /k tclsh with python, but it didn't work.

Comment: You should leave the /K and don't add "python" command. Just to be sure, I have installed Python on my Win-7 machine and tested it. Check my answer I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test it personally at the moment, but I found some people using `Python.CreateEngine()` in their code, example:

```
Microsoft.Scripting.Hosting.ScriptEngine engine = 
    IronPython.Hosting.Python.CreateEngine();
```

This line was taken from [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9080714/1816426).

You can also check [this article](http://underthehood.ironworks.com/2011/04/executing-python-code-in-net-using-ironpython.html) with example class using python code. It also uses `Python.CreateEngine()`.

Comment: AS YOU CAN SEE FROM THE QUESTION ABOVE I HAVE ALREADY DONE THAT BUT EVERYTIME IT IS THROWING EXCEPTION.

Comment: In your question I see that you use `CreateRuntime`, so I thought maybe using `CreateEngine` could make a difference. What is the exception you get? Please place it in your question.

Comment: @konrad......i tried your method also, but it's throwing the same import exception, though when i am running my program directly from the cmd.exe it's running perfectly fine..

Answer (score 0):

i have tried the following code and it seems to solve my problem:

```
Process p = new Process();
            string cmd = @"python filepath & exit";
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            p.Start();
            StreamWriter myStreamWriter = p.StandardInput;
            myStreamWriter.WriteLine(cmd.ToString());
            myStreamWriter.Close();
            string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            p.WaitForExit();
            Console.ReadLine();
```